# Is it possible to setup Monit to send alerts to Nagios

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, nagios, monit

I am trying to setup Monit on an auto-scaled group of machines. Ideally I would like monit to send alerts to my nagios service (which is already configured to escalate alerts).

I have found this [old post](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/monit-general/2006-08/msg00002.html) which asked for such a feature, but I cannot find any documentation that describes this. Is it possible to setup custom alerting in Monit?

Best regards

EDIT:
I know I could write a bash script that sends passive checks to Nagios, and execute it with an `exec` command, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution, using the `alert` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the monit docs, it seems that `alert` is strictly for sending email.

You can use email as a delivery method for Nagios checks by sending the alerts to an email address that gets piped to a script (rather than being delivered to a mailbox), like [mail2mon](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Passive-Checks/mail2mon/details). The script then submits a passive check to Nagios.

If that's not viable, there are a number of ways you can have Nagios poll for similar information. At a minimum, you could use [check_file_age](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_file_age.html) on the pid file, or [check_logfiles](https://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_logfiles/index.html) to look for monit events in syslog.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think I will probably use the check_logfiles approach, as I already use rsyslog. I think I will use  Monit to write to a local log file if there are problems, and forward this to Nagios instance.